# How to write new data inside Swift Data object

Tags: swift, pdf, nsdata, digital-signature

I'm trying to embed a PKCS#7 digital signature into a PDF using [Debenu (Foxit) Quick PDF Library](https://www.debenu.com/products/development/debenu-pdf-library/) for iOS. Based on the example code they provided, I'll have to write the signature (in hexadecimal format) inside the PDF file byte array. Here's the example code written in C#:

```
public int Sign(string pdfLocation, byte[] hexSignature, int signaturePlaceholderLength, int signaturePlaceholderStartPosition)
{
    if (hexSignature.Length < signaturePlaceholderLength)
    {
        // Write the signature into the placeholder
        using (BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(new FileStream(pdfLocation, FileMode.Open)))
        {
            writer.BaseStream.Seek(signaturePlaceholderStartPosition, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            writer.BaseStream.Write(hexSignature, 0, hexSignature.Length);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        AddLog("Error: digital signature is larger than the placeholder size");
    }
}
```

I'm having trouble to write the same algorithm in Swift because I can't figure out how to write the signature to my PDF `Data` object:

```
func sign(pdfDocument: Data, hexSignature: String, signaturePlaceholderLength: Int, signaturePlaceholderStartPosition: Int) {
    if hexSignature.count < signaturePlaceholderLength {
        // how can I add hexSignature inside pdfDocument on signaturePlaceholderStartPosition?
    }
}
```

I saw `Data.write` function, but it writes the content of the Data to a location.

There's also `Data.insert` which inserts an `UInt8` at the specified position, but my signature is a `String` (hexadecimal).

I tried to search for `Swift insert String inside Data object`, but couldn't find anything helpful.

So, am I misunderstanding something about `Data` objects and how to work with them on Swift? Do I have to transform my signature into something `Data` can handle? Or there's some helper class which I have to use to insert new data inside a `Data` object?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just change your hexSignature into a [UInt8]?
Since is what you are doing in C#

```
let hexSignatureBytes: [UInt8] = Array(hexSignature.utf8)
```